# Node js script not starting up, async * Unexpected Token

Tags: node.js, discord.js, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run my node script with `node .` on Ubuntu 18.04

It worked successfully on previous machine. This is a new setup and running into this error.

```
/var/www/html/node_bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/Collector.js:203
  async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageCollector.js:3:19)
```

My node version is v8.10.0 on all accounts including root.

I have tried chowning the files to root and running from root, same error.

Am I missing a package or something? Thanks

Comment: What was the node version on the old machine? Did you do a lift and place of the old install or did you download it fresh via npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a newer node version.

From library documentation

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js

**Installation**

Node.js **10.2.0 or newer** is required.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to node v10.18.1 and it works.